# Formatting Group Names from multiple rows into a single row (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working primarily with three tables: Customer(cID), Groups(gID, cID), and GroupDefinitions (gID). The values in parenthesis are Primary Keys and Foreign Keys.

- Customer: Contains customer information, including a GroupID.
- Groups: Contains group associations. There may be multiple Customer ID's (cID) in this table if the customer is assigned to multiple groups.
- GroupDefinitions: Contains descriptions for the groups (e.g. VIPs, Region 1)

I can write a query that will put this information together (sample below) but it will return multiple rows, one for each group the customer is in. What I need is to get each Group Name into separate columns in one row but I can't figure it out. How might I go about doing something like this?

```
Select c.cID, g.Name
from customers c
left join Groups g  ON c.CID = g.cID
left join GroupDefinitions gd  ON gd.gID = g.gID;
```

Comment: Check PIVOT to get separate columns, or LISTAGG to get them all in the same column.

Comment: I learned a few things today. PIVOT was just what I needed. Thank you.